# Accessing a video file outside sandbox

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sandbox, file-management

What is the process for accessing a video file on an iPhone so I can transfer it via Bluetooth?

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
```

How can I access the file system on the iPhone? By using `NSFileManager` I can only access the files in the application's sandbox.

Comment: Where is the video file located? If it's in another's app sandbox than you won't be able to access it. If it's in the Camera Roll than you can use an `UIImagePickerViewController` to get it.

Comment: You can't access files outside the sandbox because... it's a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can't access any other content besides the controllers that provide files(like UIImagePickerViewController) and stuff on the internet.

Comment: K Thank you. But can we access images existed in the iPhone (by using UIImagePickerViewController)?

Comment: I believe so. I think you have to be the delegate of the controller and present it. Once the user selects an image or video, it send the file back by informing the delegate(the controller that wanted the information) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can access video content in the users Photos through `AssetsLibrary` and `AVFoundation` (using `AVAssetReader`), but you can only decode frames this way, you cannot transfer the video file as-is.

Comment: I think you are referring to AVAssetReader and not ALAssetReader.